# display error message after submitting a form

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have a registration form in which i have placed a check on email id and status so that a person cannot signup again with the same email. Both the form and script are on a single page and the page is in .php format. The problem is that although the check works fine but i am not able to display an error message in front of email box. would appreciate if someone could help me

```
<form role="form" action="" autocomplete="off" method="POST">

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="name" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Company Name" required>
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email address" required>
    </div>
    <span><?php echo $errormsg;?></span>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
            <input  type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="tel" id="tel" class="form-control" name="phoneno" pattern="\d{10}" placeholder="Please enter a ten digit phone number" required />
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>
    <input class="form-control" value="" type="hidden" name="status">

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" type="submit">Sign Up</button>

</form>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
$phoneno = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phoneno']);
$status = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['status']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE email='".$email."' AND status='1'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $errormsg="email already exist";
}
else
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO register (name,email,password,phoneno,status) VALUES ('$name','$email','$password','$phoneno','1')";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    exit;
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 it is still not displaying the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all code is in single file then you shift the PHP code above the html code, why the error is not showing the html is rendering first before executing the PHP code? i.e:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
$phoneno = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phoneno']);
$status = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['status']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE email='".$email."' AND status='1'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $errormsg="email already exist";
    }
else{
$sql="INSERT INTO register (name,email,password,phoneno,status) VALUES ('$name','$email','$password','$phoneno','1')";
        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }
        exit;
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
<form role="form" action="" autocomplete="off" method="POST">

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="name" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Company Name" required>
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email address" required>
    </div>
    <?php echo $errormsg;?></span>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
            <input  type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="tel" id="tel" class="form-control" name="phoneno" pattern="\d{10}" placeholder="Please enter a ten digit phone number" required />
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>
    <input class="form-control" value="" type="hidden" name="status">

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" type="submit">Sign Up</button>

</form>
```

Comment: i would like to ask one more thing, when the page gets loaded for the first time then also the error message is getting displayed. can u plz tell me how to rectify it

Comment: these code need to execute only in case of POST, so put entire PHP code into if($_POST){--YOUR CODE HERE--}

Answer (score 1):

You should set/initialize the error container above, and make those checking above the html first.

And don't forget to use prepared statements!

```
<?php

$errormsg = '';
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email =  $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$phoneno = $_POST['phoneno'];
$status = $_POST['status'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE email = ? AND status = '1' ";
$check = $con->prepare($sql);
$check->bind_param('s', $email);
$check->execute();

if ($check->num_rows > 0) {
    $errormsg = "email already exist";
}
else{

    $sql = "INSERT INTO register (name,email,password,phoneno,status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, '1')";
    $insert = $con->prepare($sql);
    $insert->bind_param('ssss', $name, $email, $password, $phoneno);
    $insert->execute();

}
?>
<form role="form" action="" autocomplete="off" method="POST">

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="name" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Company Name" required>
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email address" required>
    </div>
    <?php echo $errormsg; ?></span>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
            <input  type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="tel" id="tel" class="form-control" name="phoneno" pattern="\d{10}" placeholder="Please enter a ten digit phone number" required />
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>
    <input class="form-control" value="" type="hidden" name="status">

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" type="submit">Sign Up</button>

</form>
```